# How to automatically retry commands on Morphia/Mongo Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, configuration, connection, morphia

Here at our company, we have an app deployed to Amazon that uses mongo as its database, using Morphia on top of the Mongo Java Driver.

However, sometimes we experience some communication issues, and some queries, inserts and updates made to mongo end up failing. We would like to tell morphia (or more likely, the mongo java driver) to automatically retry a failed command a certain number of times, independently of the reason (whether it is a network/connection failure, a socket timeout exception, or even a bad query or something like that).

We could try and wrap our mongo calls in a try/retry block, but it would require some major refactoring on our code, and it probably still would not catch every call made to mongo by morphia.

We have found some interesting options on the Mongo Java Driver documentation, such as the *autoConnectRetry* and the *socketKeepAlive*, but they seem to only address network failures, and they don't seem to be working on our setup.

Is there some other configuration option we can use to achieve this? If not, how would you guys suggest we approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are no facilities in either the driver or in morphia to retry commands.  You'll have to manage that yourself.